# Ocelot gateway startup time is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, ocelot

I have an API Gateway using ocelot 15.0.6 which includes more than 1500 routes.

Startup time of the API gateway process is very slow, about 4 minutes.

Is there any quick or easy way to improve startup time?

Comment: With "1500 APIs" you mean a ocelot configuration having that many explicit routes?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: You might want to try asking on github then https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot Having that many routes does not feel common. In system i designed i typically have just a route to find the proper microservice so have no experience if there is a problem with startup of large configurations.